# How to find and store the paritcular attribute and its value?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Lets consider I'm having the

```
<li>this is li</li>
<li class="c1" data="this is data">ineinieni </li>
<li class="c1" >ineinieni </li>
<li data="this is the data1">ineinieni </li>
<li data="this is the data2">ineinieni </li>
```

Here I want to get only the value of the data attribute as below

```
this is data
this is data1
this is data2
```

So I have tried using pattern matching as follows `<li[^>]*?data\s*=\s*"\s*([^>]*?)\s*"[^>]*?>` with `re.findall` but this is throwing error.

Is there any way to find get the values using the Beautiful soup, I have tried the following one but throwing error like `'keyerror:data'`

```
for j in contSoup.find_all("li"):
    print j['data']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this simple method:

```
>>> html = '''<li>this is li</li>
<li class="c1" data="this is data">ineinieni </li>
<li class="c1" >ineinieni </li>
<li data="this is the data1">ineinieni </li>
<li data="this is the data2">ineinieni </li>
'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
>>> for li in soup.find_all('li', {'data': True}):
        print(li['data'])    

this is data
this is the data1
this is the data2
```

Or to store it:

```
>>> data = [x['data'] for x in soup.find_all('li', {'data': True})]
>>> data
['this is data', 'this is the data1', 'this is the data2']
```

Comment: This is working for the `data=True` if suppose my input tag is some other `data-description` throwing error like `key word can't be a expression`

Answer (score 1):

You can access the data by utilizing the `__getitem__` method of the `bs4` object:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
s = """
<li>this is li</li>
<li class="c1" data="this is data">ineinieni </li>
<li class="c1" >ineinieni </li>
<li data="this is the data1">ineinieni </li>
<li data="this is the data2">ineinieni </li>
"""
s = soup(s, 'lxml')
final_data = [re.sub('the\s', '', i['data']) for i in s.find_all('li') if re.findall('data\=', str(i))]
```

Output:

```
['this is data', 'this is data1', 'this is data2']
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error because some of your `<li>` tags don't have a `data` attribute, which means that `j["data"]` is a `KeyError`.

To avoid this, search using a method that lets you filter those out. `select` is a good way; it lets you use the compact CSS selector syntax to find the elements you want. To find only `<li>` tags with a `data` attribute, try:

```
for li in contSoup.select("li[data]"):
    print li["data"]
```

Adding `data=True` to the `find_all()` as Keyur shows is another way.